# Swift reloading data in table view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

PREFACE: Apologies for any mistakes here, I'm still pretty new to programming and trying to learn!

After initially storing the following data in two separate files I have managed to load each data set into a separate table view with a segue to transition between them:

```
class PcTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//SI. Initialises pcs with an empty array of objects to store PC details.
var pcs = [Pc]()

//SI. Creates data in a function "loadTestPcs".
func loadTestPcs()
{
    let pic1 = UIImage(named: "MON1")
    let pc1 = Pc(image: pic1, name: "PC1", graphics: "Radeon R7", cpu: "A6", hdd: 1, ssd:  0, ram:  8, sku: 4643466, price: 499.99)

    let pic2 = UIImage(named: "PC2")
    let pc2 = Pc(image: pic2, name: "PC2", graphics: "Radeon R7", cpu: "A6", hdd: 1, ssd:  0, ram:  8, sku: 4643466, price: 549.99)

    let pic3 = UIImage(named: "PC3")
    let pc3 = Pc(image: pic3, name: "PC3", graphics: "Radeon R7", cpu: "A6", hdd: 1, ssd:  0, ram:  8, sku: 4643466, price: 599.99)

    //SI. adds details stored in pc1,2 and 3 to pcs array.
    //
    pcs += [pc1!, pc2!, pc3!]
}
```

and

```
class monitorTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//SI. Initialises monitors with an empty array of objects to store PC details.
var monitors = [Monitors]()

//SI. Creates data in a function "loadTestMonitors".
func loadTestMonitors()
{
    let pic1 = UIImage(named: "MON1")
    let mon1 = Monitors(image: pic1, name: "Acer Pedator", screenSize: "24", resolution: "A6", details: "IPS ZeroFrame Gaming Widescreen Monitor", sku: 4643466, price: 499.99)

    let pic2 = UIImage(named: "MON2")
    let mon2 = Monitors(image: pic2, name: "PC2", screenSize: "Radeon R7", resolution: "A6", details: "TN G-Sync 144Hz Gaming Widescreen LED Monitor", sku: 4643466, price: 549.99)

    let pic3 = UIImage(named: "MON3")
    let mon3 = Monitors(image: pic3, name: "PC3", screenSize: "Radeon R7", resolution: "A6", details: "IPS SuperWidescreen LED Monitor", sku: 4643466, price: 599.99)

    //SI. adds details stored in pc1,2 and 3 to monitors array.
    //
    monitors += [mon1!, mon2!, mon3!]
}
```

I am now trying to store all the data in one location with the table view (initially displaying pc data) reloading as a row is selected (the item in that row should be stored for use on a summary page later) and then the table view should be loaded with the second set of data.

After following an apple tutorial for a food tracker and looking through table view documentation I am at a standstill.

If anyone is able to help I would be most grateful :)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, currently you have two table view controllers, but you want to only have one, which first displays the first data set and then the second?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. I don't understand what you mean by "reloading as a row is selected". Are you saying that the tableView reloads every time someone taps a row in that table?

Comment: @TimVermeulen yes, exactly.

Comment: @ryantxr yes, it's a pc builder - the idea is that a user can tap a row to select a PC (which is then stored to be accessed later), the tableView then reloads with the second set of data, the user again taps to select a monitor (which is again stored). Hope this clears things up :)

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't reuse the same table view like that. Instead make two separate table view controllers with a segue from the cell of the first table view to the second controller.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this but cannot get the data to load in the second view controller.

Comment: `  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        //SI. after creating a seague on the main storyboard
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowMonitorsSeague" , sender: indexPath)
        
    }`

Comment: This was the code I used to perform the segue. The segue does run but the second table view displays no data

Comment: Try to drag the segue in your storyboard directly from the prototype cell to the destination view controller, that way you don't have to override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or perform the segue manually. Then in `prepareForSegue`, you can access the next controller with `segue.destinationViewController` and send the values it needs to show.